# Is it possible to create hierarchical enums?

Tags: c#, enums

I want to create a hierarchical enum that represents a type that I can pass as a parameter.

The data structure looks like this:

```
enum Cars
{
   Ford { Corsair, Cortina, Galaxy, GT },
   Ferrari { Testarossa, California, Enzo },
   ...
}
```

I wish to call a function with the following signature:

```
public void BuildCar(Cars car);
```

Like this:

```
BuildCar(Cars.Ferrari.Enzo);
```

Basically, I want to enforce the car/manufacturer relationship in the type.

Comment: Added some tt code, check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought about answering this with extensions and/or `ICustomEnum` stuff.

Then I thought - is there anything really that bad with the following? :-)

```
    enum Cars
    {
       Ford_Corsair,
       Ford_Cortina,
       Ford_Galaxy,
       Ford_GT,

       Ferrari_Testarossa,
       Ferrari_California,
       Ferrari_Enzo,
    }
```

Your function still looks like:

```
public void BuildCar(Cars car);
```

Your call looks like:

```
BuildCar(Cars.Ferrari_Enzo);
```

Comment: This solution conflicts with Open Close principle. With this one I really don't like to be in conflict ;)

Comment: No, it is not a solution. In case of real hierarchy children inherits the value of the parent too. Meaning if something is Enzo, that is also a Ferrari like (in your pseudo language) if foo=Cars.Ferrari.Enzo, then the condition foo=Cars.Ferrari is true

Answer (score 6):

Do-it-yourself solution:

```
class Cars
{
    private static int CurrentId = 0;

    private readonly int id;

    private Cars()
    {
        id = CurrentId;
        CurrentId++;
    }

    public static class Ford
    {
        public static Cars Corsair = new Cars();
        public static Cars Cortina = new Cars();
        public static Cars Galaxy = new Cars();
        public static Cars GT = new Cars();
    }

    public static class Ferrari
    {
        public static Cars Testarossa = new Cars();
        public static Cars California = new Cars();
        public static Cars Enzo = new Cars();
    }

    // Add overrides of Equals and GetHash from id
}
```

You will lose all features contained in `Enums` class this way. But that is understandable, because you want logic that is not normally supported.

Comment: i think that depending on usage pattern each model will receive different id on each app run.

Comment: Yeah. That might be a problem. You can assign Ids explicitly in constructor, but that would be little tiresome.

Comment: Maybe it would be good to make the static fields `Corsair`, `Cortina`, and so on `readonly`?

Comment: I find that this structure is not useable as a parameter in a custom attribute. Though it seems to work in other cases.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can get this:

```
BuildCar(Cars.Ferrari.Enzo)
```

But you are not going to get this:

```
enum Cars
{
   Ford { Corsair, Cortina, Galaxy, GT },
   Ferrari { Testarossa, California, Enzo },
   ...
}
```

What you can do is a sealed class with private constructor which exposes intances in a kind of tree structure, for which you will need some helper class.

The following code works:

```
using System;

namespace _2DEnum
{
    public class Example
    {
        public void BuildCar(Cars car)
        {
            GC.KeepAlive(car);
        }

        public void ExampleUse()
        {
            BuildCar(Cars.Ferrari.Enzo);
        }
    }

    public sealed class Cars
    {
        private readonly string _value;

        private Cars(string value)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(value, null))
            {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
            }
            else
            {
                _value = value;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return _value;
        }

        public static class Ferrari
        {
            private static readonly Cars _California = new Cars("California");
            private static readonly Cars _Enzo = new Cars("Enzo");
            private static readonly Cars _Testarossa = new Cars("Testarossa");

            public static Cars California
            {
                get { return Ferrari._California; }
            }

            public static Cars Enzo
            {
                get { return Ferrari._Enzo; }
            }

            public static Cars Testarossa
            {
                get { return Ferrari._Testarossa; }
            }
        }

        public static class Ford
        {
            private static readonly Cars _Corsair = new Cars("Corsair");
            private static readonly Cars _Cortina = new Cars("Cortina");
            private static readonly Cars _Galaxy = new Cars("Galaxy");
            private static readonly Cars _GT = new Cars("GT");

            public static Cars Corsair
            {
                get { return Ford._Corsair; }
            }

            public static Cars Cortina
            {
                get { return Ford._Cortina; }
            }

            public static Cars Galaxy
            {
                get { return Ford._Galaxy; }
            }

            public static Cars GT
            {
                get { return Ford._GT; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then again, you may try to use some Text Transformation Templates to be able to type it like an enum.

Kudos to @[Euphoric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12032387/402022)... I need an over-analysis badge.

---

### Text Tranformation Templates!

I've created a solution for T4 that uses a file Enum2D.ttinclude that holds the code to generate this 2D enums and a file for each of your "2D enums", for example Cars.tt.

First Enum2D.ttinclude:

```
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #><#+
    public string BuildEnum2D
    (
        string namespaceName,
        string enumName,
        IEnumerable<Tuple<string, IEnumerable<string>>> items
    )
    {
        string head =
@"
using System;

namespace @namespace
{
    public sealed class @enum
    {
        private readonly string _value;

        private @enum(string value)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(value, null))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(""value"");
            }
            else
            {
                _value = value;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return _value;
        }";
        head = head.Replace("@namespace", namespaceName);
        head = head.Replace("@enum", enumName);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(head);
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            sb.Append(
@"

        public static class " + item.Item1 + 
@"
        {"
                    );
            foreach (var entry in item.Item2)
            {
                sb.Append(
@"
            private static readonly Cars _" + entry + @" = new Cars(""" + entry + 
@""");"
                        );
            }

            foreach (var entry in item.Item2)
            {
                sb.Append(
@"

            public static Cars " + entry + @"
            {
                get { return _" + entry + @"; }
            }"
                        );
            }
            sb.Append(
@"
        }"          );

        }
        sb.Append(
@"
    }
}"
                );
        return "// <auto-generated />" + "\r\n" + sb.ToString();
    }
#>
```

As you can see, this file defines a function `BuildEnum2D` that has the only purpose of generating the code for your 2D enum given the parameters. Now all we need is to call it. For that we will use Cars.tt as follows:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ include file="Enum2D.ttinclude" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #><#=
    BuildEnum2D
    (
        "Enum2DTest",
        "Cars",
        new Tuple<string, IEnumerable<string>>[]
        {
            new Tuple<string, IEnumerable<string>>
            (
                "Ferrari",
                new string[]
                {
                    "California",
                    "Enzo",
                    "Testarossa"
                }
            ),
            new Tuple<string, IEnumerable<string>>
            (
                "Ford",
                new string[]
                {
                    "Corsair",
                    "Cortina",
                    "Galaxy",
                    "GT"
                }
            )
        }
    )
#>
```

As you can see we include the file Enum2D.ttinclude and then call the function Build2DEnum, the parameters are the namespace, the enum name and the items. This way you will be able to create more of these 2D enums and hopefully maintingin the tt files is not too much pain.

Cheers!

Comment: definition of overengineering?

Comment: @Peri when laziness is a virtue :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use an Enum to define all cars, then use static members on a class for each Manufacturer to return the allowed values:

```
enum Car {
  FordCorsair,
  FordCortina,
  FordGalaxy,
  FordGT,
  FerrariTestarossa,
  FerrariCalifornia,
  FerrariEnzo,
  ...
}

public sealed class Ford {
  public const Car Corsair = Car.FordCorsair;
  public const Car Cortina = Car.FordCortina;
  public const Car Galaxy = Car.FordGalaxy;
  public const Car GT = Car.GT;
}

public sealed class Ferrari {
  public const Car Testarossa = Car.FerrariTestarossa;
  public const Car California = Car.FerrariCalifornia;
  public const Car Enzo = Car.FerrariEnzo;
  public const Car GT = Car.GT;
}

...
Car mycar = Ford.Corsair;
```

Of course, the syntactic sugar benefits of this may not be worth the pain of keeping the actual enum synchronized with the constant class members.

Aside from the above, using string constants is likely your best option. Enums can't be nested or inherited, and they can't share a common interface that would allow values for the same Enum type to be specified in different namespaces or classes.

Answer (score 0):

you could create Cars class that would contain nested class for each make that would contain consts for each model

Comment: But you can't get type safety or intellisense when calling the BuildCar method then.

Answer (score 0):

I have built some sort of nested enum using Custom Attributes

```
public class MyParentTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyParentType MyParentType { get; protected set; }

    public MyParentTypeAttribute(MyParentType myParentType)
    {
        MyParentType = myParentType;
    }
}



public enum MyParentType 
{ 
    Parent1,
    Parent2
}




public enum MyChildType
{
    [MyParentType(MyParentType.Parent1)]
    Child1,

    [MyParentType(MyParentType.Parent1)]
    Child2,
    
    [MyParentType(MyParentType.Parent1)]
    Child3,
    
    [MyParentType(MyParentType.Parent2)]
    Child4,
    
    [MyParentType(MyParentType.Parent2)]
    Child5
}
```

You can then create some easy methods to check which ParentType is related to the child type... Might not be the nicest way, but it works.